# Scripting Linux to install several programs at once

Tags: linux, scripting, video-processing, codec

I've been installing step by step video conversion codec and tools for a few hours now, and it is just plan annoying.  Is it possible to design a script to load in linux to do all the commands in sequence one after another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.  Create a plain text file, put #! /bin/bash at the top, then write all the commands in the file.  Save it, "chmod +x yourFile", then run it by calling ./yourFile.

If your installs are a more intricate, I'd need to see an example to say more specifically how to do this as a shell script.

Comment: they simple rather straight forward. for example,

d /usr/src
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/files/opencore-amr/0.1.2/opencore-amr-0.1.2.tar.gz/download
tar -zxvf opencore-amr-0.1.2.tar.gz
cd opencore-amr-0.1.2
./configure
make
make install

Comment: cd /usr/src
svn checkout -r 17000 http://svn.xiph.org/trunk/vorbis/ vorbis
cd vorbis
./autogen.sh
make
make install

Comment: cd /usr/src
svn checkout -r 25620 svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg

./configure –prefix=/usr/local –enable-pthreads –enable-pic –enable-gpl –enable-version3 –enable-libmp3lame –enable-nonfree –enable-libopencore-amrnb –enable-libopencore-amrwb –enable-libvorbis –disable-mmx –enable-shared –enable-libxvid –enable-libx264 –enable-libfaac

make
make install

Comment: All of those commands are really straight forward, and you can add them to a script to automate the process.